# Stripe subscription API returning an empty subscription list for my customer in Flutter even though payment is successful

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

[successful payment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aQtr.png) I've two subscription plans in my stripe account right and I'm fetching them in the app when a user subscribes I can see the payment in the dashboard as successful but when u try to retrieve the subscriptions list against the customer id using stripes API it returns an empty list

response:

```
{  
"object": "list", 
"data": [],"
has_more": false,
"url": "/v1/subscriptions"}
```

Comment: The picture you shared is about a one-time payment not a Subscription. Maybe you are using a third-party that creates one-time payments each month but no Subscription in Stripe? You likely want to talk directly to Stripe's support team really for this: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: @koopajah but i do have subscriptions in stripe account

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't really share much details. You didn't share code, you didn't confirm you are on the right account or what happens if you look at one of those Subscriptions in the Dashboard to find the `sub_123` id and then call the Retrieve Subscription API: <https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve>. Working with Stripe's support team seems better here

Comment: @koopajah thank you so much! i was able to solve the issue with stripe support teams help thankyouuuu